# Custom loggers are lost when using Java Spark

Tags: java, logging, log4j, spark-java

I have an already developed component which I am now trying to use as a microservice, so I added a pretty simple spark layer for making requests.

However, the component uses log4j for logging. I have set up log4j both automatically and programmatically, and on both cases the appender my component has writes just the spark messages. The output is below:

```
LOG4J config file is missing
Configuring Log4J: /Users/alberto.cruz/WsCor/WsCor_log4j.properties
0 [Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - Logging initialized @7196ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
519 [Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer  - == Spark has ignited ...
519 [Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer  - >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567
```

The first message is something spark generates, it complains about not having a log4j configuration file. The second is a message generated by my application, which detects a lack of log4j appenders and programmatically configures log4j. The third message gets written by java spark itself. It's as if it configures log4j again.

Then I tried putting the log4j.properties it in the default package on the spark application, to no avail. Log4J configures correctly (The first and second messages do not appear on the output), but none of my appenders seem to be configured (this is, only the spark output is getting written on every appender).

Where can I configure log4j appenders when using spark?